# Org-mode: changing temporarily font size for LaTeX export

Tags: org-mode, latex

I need to change the font size of part of my text (actually
mostly to fit a table, which might be an extra-step).

Following a org-mode discussion somewhere, I have tried the following, which does not work for me in spacemacs 0.3 with Emacs 27:

```
    #+title: Test changing font size 



* Text
Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,
sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos

#+begin_latex
{\scriptsize 
#+end_latex
| Table | Column  |
|-------+---------|
| Row   | Content |

#+begin_latex
}
#+end_latex

#+begin_latex
{\ssmall 
#+end_latex
qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est
#+begin_latex
}
#+end_latex
```

Regards,

Trad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There *used* to be a `#+begin_latex` (or `#_begin_html` or ...) block, but it no longer exists.

Try this instead:

```
* Text
Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,
sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos

#+latex: {\scriptsize 
| Table | Column  |
|-------+---------|
| Row   | Content |

#+latex: }
```

which is simpler and works through all Org mode releases (AFAIK).

Alternatively, this should also work:

```
#+begin_export latex
{\scriptsize
#+end_export
| Table | Column  |
|-------+---------|
| Row   | Content |

#+begin_export latex
}
#+end_export
```

but it is longer and the markup obscures things (but it is more convenient for large, multi-line LaTeX code insertions).

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly it. Much appreciated.